# Object to ArrayList to JList and back again (A few questions)

Tags: java, xml, object, arraylist, jlist

**Program Outline:**
I plan to make a simple Java program that will load Vehicle objects (Vehicle being the superclass, EnginedVehicle and GoodsVehicle being the subclasses) from an XML file into an ArrayList which will then be displayed on a JList. The user will be able to show/hide the different Vehicle types using check boxes, add a new vehicle type or press the selected item in the JList and edit or delete it. The program will then put the Objects back into the ArrayList where it can be then saved back to the XML file.

**Question:** So, I am completely fine with the loading of the XML file into the ArrayList and putting that object onto the JList but the thing that is hurting my head is thinking about how I am going to:

1. What is the best way of getting the object back from the JList ready for it to be modified or deleted and put back into the ArrayList?
2. How would I show/hide the different types of Vehicles in the JList using the check boxes?

I understand this may seem a lot but, this is my first post and I am new to the community and I have fairly good knowledge of Java and OOP programming but I have just finished writing a fairly big website and going back to Java is a headache.

Comment: Do you really need to change to JList and back again? I dont see the need for that?

Comment: I guess not? I am open for suggestions though if you think not. I was just thinking if I have a method that saves the objects back to XML, it would be easier to keep them all in the same ArrayList. Just trying to plan it out in my head before I go and do it.

Answer (score 0):

Since your ArrayList should be equal in size (item count) to your JList, your JList will have the index you're interested based on selection.  Regardless if you want to modify or delete the item, store what index it was at and remove the item from the JList (You should be using a DefaultListModel).  Use this index value to get the object from your ArrayList.  If you're modifying, modify your object as needed, you shouldn't have to remove the object from the ArrayList for modifications, and place it back into your DefaultListModel.  If it's a delete, then just remove the object from your ArrayList using the index value you stored.

As far as displaying (show/hide), clear your DefaultListModel (which will clear your JList), iterate through your ArrayList and add the items to the DefaultListModel that match your checkbox selection criteria.

**EDIT:**

I didn't take into consideration of possibly modifying/deleting items when items are hidden.  For this, may want your objects to have a field that stores what index they are at in the ArrayList.  This way when you do your filter, I would copy the items from your "Master" ArrayList into a sub list that you can populate your DefaultListModel.  Then you apply the same logic to this sublist when selecting an item from you JList,  then take your changes from your sublist and apply them to the "Master" ArrayList.

Keep in mind that when you remove an item, you'll have to reassign all items index location from that point on down.

I'm sure there is probably a cleaner way of doing this, but this is what first comes to mind for me.

Comment: Firstly, thank you for your reply. I didn't think to remove it from the ArrayList for the modifications but to simply change what's in there already. So say the items in the JList are:
1. A car
2. A bicycle
3. A motor bike
but in my arraylist the car is at value 8. Would the JList index show the index of say 1 as its the first in the JList or 8 as it is 8th in the ArrayList? Sorry if it sounds confusing haha. Because the JList will vary in size depending on what items are shown or hidden.

Comment: It would show an index of 0 in your JList.  I didn't take into consideration that you may want to modify/delete items when you hide items from your checkbox selection.

Comment: Sorry, I may have not made myself clear enough. But yeah it would be zero haha. So would you know the way around it so that I can get the ArrayList index of the select JList item?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I'm horribly mistaken, but why change to a JList at all? Do you use your JList as a parameter to visualize the information in it? If yes, why dont you use your ArrayList instead? Then the checkboxes only change the visibility ot the Items of the List. So you dont have to care about indices, because they stay the same. And new entries, can be made as well... maybe im wrong but i guess you got kind of a GUI for the user to browse/alter/add new vehicles?

Comment: The JList is the GUI visual I want to use. So the JList and checkbox's will be used to browse the content of the ArrayList. I may be making it harder for myself but I don't know. Thanks for your reply btw.

Comment: As far as I see, JList is not a gui, it needs a (example) JScrollPane, to be visualised. Can you provide some code, otherwise it will be a needle in the heystack